# Cortana - OAuth2 Redirect URL Configuration not changing

Tags: oauth-2.0, botframework, cortana

I'm currently implementing an OAuth2 authentication using Microsoft Bot Framework and Cortana as one of my channels. However, as I was setting up my OAuth2 configuration with the following details in where I properly set the **Redirect URL** both from **Knowledge Store** and **apps.dev.microsoft.com**

Knowledge Store:
[image]

apps.dev.microsoft.com:
[image]

Whenever I authenticate to Cortana based from the OAuth2 that I've configured, the redirect URI seems to be always set as **https://www.bing.com/agents/oauth**. Here's a screenshot of the http request from Cortana Authentication that I got from fiddler:

[image]

Which causes this error message:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @JasonSowers not yet

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the bot channel (in this case Cortana) needs to be where the redirect points to.  Cortana's redirect is https://www.bing.com/agents/oauth.
[Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/configure-connected-account).  You can test OAuth via botframework and the emulator.  In that case, the redirect is https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect. [Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). If you look at the diagram in [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) on page 10, you'll see that Cortana is the client.  The auth call needs to come back to her.  You also need to let the auth server know that the redirect URL is allowed.  For Microsoft login, you go [to the app dev portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), select your app, go add a "web platform" and register the redirect urls.  That should solve the problem on both ends.